# console.log in karma angularjs method testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm a little confused as to why I am getting `undefined` as a return value for a function I am testing.

here is the function I'm testing :

```
 $scope.entityItemsIntoObjectChecked = function (entityItems) {
    newEntityWithChecked = entityItems.map(function (value) {
        return { "val": value, "checked": false }; 
    });
    shareDataService.setEntityArray(newEntityWithChecked);
}
```

and part of my test suite :

```
it("should arrange an array into ovject with extra value for entities + depots", inject(function (shareDataService) {
        var dummyEntityArray = ["ent1", "ent2", "ent3"];
        var expectedObjectArray = [{ val: "ent1", checked: false }, { val: 'ent2', checked: false }, { val: 'ent3', checked: false }];

        expect(mainScope.entityItemsIntoObjectChecked).toBeDefined();
        mainScope.entityItemsIntoObjectChecked(dummyEntityArray);
        console.log(mainScope.entityItemsIntoObjectChecked(dummyEntityArray))
}))
```

I'm expecting the line `console.log(mainScope.entityItemsIntoObjectChecked(dummyEntityArray))` to output my array based on the array `dummyEntityArray` which I have passed in previously on the line `mainScope.entityItemsIntoObjectChecked(dummyEntityArray);`

but I get `undefined` on console.log.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$scope.entityItemsIntoObjectChecked` method does not return anything so the return value will be `undefined`.

You can either return the `newEntityWithChecked` array from the method or spy on your `shareDataService.setEntityArray` method to verify that the expected array is being passed.

You can read the documentation on spies here: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

Comment: is it possible to call a function within jasmine and assign a var to it?  for example I want `mainScope.entityItemsIntoObjectChecked(dummyEntityArray);` to be assigned to a var, then passed into my next step of testing which would be `expect(mainScope.methodWhichChangesArrayToObject(mainScope.entityItemsIntoObjectChecked(dummyEntityArray)).toEqual( <<object within array>>)`

Comment: By next step do you mean another spec? It is generally not advisable to have one spec to depend on another. You can just call the necessary methods in your spec where you want to test `methodWhichChangesArrayToObject`

Comment: Ok this clears things up for me.  Thanks a lot.  Getting my head around this testing is hard, mainly because it seems to easy if you know what I mean?  I keep thinking im missing something HUGE...